# Can we use 2 database joins in a single transformation in Pentaho?

Tags: join, pentaho

I am trying to create a transformation which requires to join 3 tables. One being the input transformation and others using database joins. My question is can I use 2 database joins in a singe transformation? If not whats the alternative to it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can use as many as you want. Is your transform above not working? If not please post error messages, etc.

Comment: I didn't get to test it yet was waiting for connection specifications. In the mean while I wanted to know if it was logically correct.

Comment: Yes you can. However if all of the tables are in the same database you should just do it in a query in the Fact User Offer step.  The database will usually be able to do joins faster than PDI.

Comment: As Brian said, you can use as many DB lookups as you want. However, that's a rather slow step, so try to avoid them if performance is an issue.